# Filezilla FTP stops working after 3-4 uploads

Tags: windows-7, ftp, filezilla, godaddy

I am using Filezilla to transfer website files to a Godaddy server.
Problem is after 3 or 4 uploads Filezilla starts giving me "software caused connection abort" and will not upload the file.

It does however make the server file I was trying to overwrite to be 0kb which can crash the site until I can get Filezilla transferring again.

Restarting the computer seems to make it work for another 3-4 uploads again.

I have tried disabling my anti-virus and firewall but it made no difference.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try another ftp client to see where is the trouble: Use WinSCP on windows www.winscp.net or gFTP or konqueror on linux.

Comment: @maudam I just noticed the port number wasn't saved. I will have to test further to see if that was it all along.